# Как использовать внешний конфигурационный файл

Tags: java

В Spring при запуске jar можно использовать spring.config.location для переопределения конфигурационных файлов.
Как это можно использовать без Spring? Чтобы конфиг не тянулся из самого jar, а брался, например, оттуда же, где и лежит сам jarник.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вы хотите что бы конфигурационный файл Spring был прочитан из вне. Если это так у вас есть несколько решений.

1. **Переадресация на другой файл**

Если вы используйте Spring Boot приложение вы можете прописать следующие строчки для указания внешнего файла конфигурации Spring. Зайдите в основной файл `application.properties` и пропишите следующую строку :

```
spring.config.location=/yuor/path/file

# Для относительного пути где лежит ваш проект используйте 
spring.config.location=./yuor/path/file
```

Таким образом когда Spring прочитает данную строчку , он загрузит файл свойств из того места которое вы указали. Это наиболее простой вариант. Таким образом `properties` файл не будет "тянуться" из самого jar а будет использовать внешний файл конфигурации

2. **Указание внешнего файла в ручную**

Вы также можете указать расположение конфигурационного класса вручную в коде, например так :

```java
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
      PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = 
      new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
      properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/Users/home/conf.properties"));
      properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
    return properties;
}
```

Здесь вы также можете использовать префикс `./` что бы указать текущую папку приложения `./your/properties.file`

3. **Указание внешнего файла в ручную при запуске**

Данный способ довольно не удобный но все же имеет место быть если вы хотите быстро запустить приложение.

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:///your/custom/config/outside.properties
```

Для дополнительной информации можете посетить официальный сайт [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) на это тему , а также сайт [Bueldang](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-properties-file-outside-jar). Надеюсь смог вам помочь